# Error while Tensorflow import using the command 'from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential'

Tags: tensorflow

cannot import name '*pywrap_dtensor_device' from 'tensorflow.python' (C:\python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py

Answer (score -2):

it is easy there are many possible way one of them is you include of eager and none eager modes.

You can specific devices for the job that is because Tensorflow 2.8 with basics configuration does not need the jobid *

They manage the schedule or you may use the manager.

**[ Eager mode] :**

```
device_spec = DeviceSpec(device_type="GPU", device_index=0)
print( device_spec )
print( device_spec.to_string() )
with tf.device(device_spec.to_string()):
    my_var = tf.Variable(1.)
    squared_var = tf.square(my_var)
    print( squared_var )
```

**[ None Eager mode] :**

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
device_spec = DeviceSpec(job="1234", device_type="GPU", device_index=0)
print( device_spec )
print( device_spec.to_string() )
with tf.device(device_spec.to_string()):
    my_var = tf.Variable(1.)
    squared_var = tf.square(my_var)
    print( squared_var )
```

**[ Output ]:**

```
<tensorflow.python.framework.device_spec.DeviceSpecV2 object at 0x000001AB1149EBE0>
/job:1234/device:GPU:0
Tensor("Square:0", shape=(), dtype=float32, device=/job:1234/device:GPU:0)
```

Comment: That is the different most people fails when change the versions.

Comment: This is yet another question you have misunderstood and you are not actually answering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunalety it didn't work.

Comment: you need to specify more information but one cause is the version of Tensorflow upgrades may do not work with the old one.